# Comparison of % change in two photos with GRASS

Tags: grass-gis, imagery

I have two aerial photos of the same location taken at two different dates. Is there a way to compare the % difference between those two images using GRASS or is there a better tool?

Sorry, also if there are other tips and tricks I am relatively new at this.

Comment: like change detection?

Comment: yep, exactly. but not just determining if it has happened, but by how much. a quantitative result.